# Delete Track not deleting in soundcloud account

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am trying to use the delete function to delete a track from the user's soundcloud account while also deleting the track from my database. It is successfully deleting the information from my database, but is not deleting from the soundcloud's database and I really cannot understand why! No errors show up until the end, but just does not delete the track from soundcloud.

This is my code I am using:

```
$(".deleteTrack").live("click", function () {
        if (SC.isConnected) {
            var scTid = $(this).attr('id');
            var path = "/tracks/" + scTid;
            var con = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this track?");
            if (con) {
                 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "JamWithInI.aspx/GetTrackInfo",
                        data: "{'scTid':'" + scTid + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(str){
                            inst = str.d["1"];
                            SC.delete(path, function(){
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "JamWithInI.aspx/DeleteTrack",
                        data: "{'scTid':'" + scTid + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(){
                            alert("Your track has been deleted");
                            $("#openInstruments").trigger('click').trigger('click');
                            $(".instrument").trigger('click').bind('click').trigger('click');
                            inst = null;
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Track did not delete succesfully");
                        }
                    });

            });
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("An error occurred");
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The SC.delete() method calls your callback with a response object and error (if any). Add something like the following to find out if things are working properly:

```
SC.delete(path, function(response, error) {
    alert(response.status);
    if (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

If your delete request was successful, you should get a single alert with the text '200 - OK'. If not, the error message will be informative.